# Scala var type usage results in type mismatch

Tags: scala

I thought that Scala `var` type is cool, helps to avoid tons of some technical code and makes it possible to concentrate on functionality. However, I now face something really strange. When I compile my program, I get an error message from `sbt`:

```
type mismatch;
found: java.sql.Connection
required: String

this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                                       ^
```

Please, pay attention that the compiler points to `conn` property of the class, and this property is defined in the class like so:

```
class Db{
   private var conn = ""

   ....
}
```

So, why does compiler care about types matching, if it is `Scala` and if I'm using `var` data type?

Comment: I provided a full error message from `sbt`.

Comment: Sorry about that, I expected the message to be under the `^`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`var` is not a data type. It is a keyword for declaring and defining a mutable variable. The type is not dynamic---it is still inferred at compile-time. In this case `conn` is inferred to be a `String`, and it is completely identical to writing

```
private var conn: String = ""
```

The whole point of Scala's type system is to disallow passing incompatible types around. It's failing because, obviously, you cannot assign an SQL connection to a variable of type `String`. Type inference does not allow you to ignore the types of objects, it just lets the compiler figure it out where possible.

Answer (score 2):

`var` is not a data type, it's one keyword used to define variables in Scala. The other one is `val`. Whether you use `var` or `val` only affects whether the variable you define can be re-assigned to (`var`) or is read-only (`val`). It does not affect the type of the variable in anyway.

Regardless of whether you use `var` or `val`, the type of a variable is either specified explicitly (by writing `: theType` after the variable name) or inferred implicitly from the value you assign it to.

In your example, you did not explicitly provide a type, so the inferred type was `String` as that is the type of `conn`.

Comment: Oh, I see. I just thought that with `var` in `Scala` I could have something, that I can not make in `Java` - to assign to a variable any type I want and to swich between types at runtime.